# illegalArgumentException occurs when using the same function in an existing Grails application

Tags: grails

I created a grails application from scratch to create a basic test application using an API. Everything worked fine there and when i put the exact same code in an existing Grails application then i got the following exception when i ran the JUnits.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value:        Basic MWU3ZWY3NDg3YzNlMzRiMDk3N2YyNzNiZGRmZTE3NTQ6

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.checkMessageHeader(HttpURLConnection.java:482)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.isExternalMessageHeaderAllowed(HttpURLConnection.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:2752)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:316)
at de.paymill.net.HttpClient.setAuthentication(HttpClient.java:230)
at de.paymill.net.HttpClient.createConnection(HttpClient.java:212)
at de.paymill.net.HttpClient.request(HttpClient.java:143)
at de.paymill.net.HttpClient.post(HttpClient.java:100)
at de.paymill.service.PaymentService.create(PaymentService.java:31)
at de.paymill.service.PaymentService$create.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.linquire.mib.service.PaymentsService.createPaymentMethod(PaymentsService.groovy:113)
at com.linquire.mib.service.PaymentsServiceIntegrationTests.createPaymentsTest(PaymentsServiceIntegrationTests.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is the test implemented in the existing application.

```
 @Test
public void createPaymentsTest() {
    System.out.println("the private api key now is: "+Paymill.getApiKey());
    String token = (String) paymentsService.getToken("4111111111111111", "123", "12", "2013");
    System.out.println(token);
    paymentsService.createPaymentMethod(token);

    assertNotNull(userService.getPaymentMethod());
    assertEquals("1111", userService.getPaymentMethodLast4());
    assertEquals("visa", userService.getPaymentMethodCardType());
}
```

Here is the code in the test application.

```
  @Test
public void createPaymentsTest() {
    System.out.println("the private api key now is: "+Paymill.getApiKey());
    String token = (String) makePaymentService.getToken("4111111111111111", "123", "12", "2013");
    System.out.println(token);
    Payment p = (Payment) makePaymentService.createPayment(token);

    System.out.println();
    assertEquals("1111", p.getLast4());
    assertEquals("visa", p.getCardType());
}
```

As you can see the codes are strikingly similar. The createPayment(token) function simply calls a function which calls an API function.
Implementation in existing application is:

```
def createPaymentMethod(String token) {
    PaymentService paymentService = Paymill.getService(PaymentService.class);

    Payment payment = paymentService.create(token);

    //Sets the PaymentMethodId field for the current user
    userService.setPaymentMethod(payment.getId());
}
```

Same function in the test application is:

```
def createPayment(String token) {
    PaymentService paymentService = Paymill.getService(PaymentService.class);
    Payment payment = paymentService.create(token);
    return paymentService.get(payment.id);
}
```

I have taken a look at possible differences in config.groovy, etc. but i can't seem to think of a reason why it would behave differently when its the exact same code (even same parameters passed, etc.)

From what i have seen, this error normally occurs due to the insertion of a CRLF characters somewhere in the HTTP request but i cant really think of some component in the existing application which might introduce such a character when sending the request.
Please let me know if someone has some idea on what might be causing this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to break the new grails application by moving things "one by one" from the older one (if it is small enough and portable).

Comment: Actually the existing application is a pretty huge project and we just need to implement the payments there using the API. The same jar has been used in both projects and the same test is being run in both.

Comment: Could any installed plugin cause such an issue ? Coz i suspect that there is something that is modifying the request URL somehow causing this error.

Comment: Understandable, but the stacktrace itself is not enough for solving this problem. Enlarge the context of the problem by adding a basic unit of work.

Comment: Edited with code snippets

Comment: In the log: 
at com.linquire.mib.service.PaymentsService.createPaymentMethod(PaymentsService.groovy:113)
com.linquire.mib.service.PaymentsServiceIntegrationTests.createPaymentsTest(PaymentsServiceIntegrationTests.java:37)
---> you will want to check that line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is usually seen due to a bug in the username/password conversion to base64: [See here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6459815).

Try the same call with a user that has a short password and username to see if the problem disappears.

Comment: I can see that it might be a problem but why would this creep up in one application and not in another. The issue here is that nothing can be debugged since the problem is coming up somewhere in between the HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection calls. According to the documentations, the PaymentService.create(token) method should work just fine (as it does in case of the test application)

Comment: Alright upon further investigation i found out that you were correct. It is the Base64.encodeBase64String() which is surprisingly giving different outputs in the 2 projects. For some reason it is returning a result with a '\r' at the end of the encoded string (which the API doesn't filter out) which results in the error in the request header. Do you have any idea why the same class might act differently in different projects. Could it have something to do with the versions. Class is org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Comment: Depends on the version of the base64 encoder, the JVM, everything. You didn't provide information in your question, so I assumed all of them were consistent between the two projects. In that case I had to assume the credentials themselves were different.

Comment: In the code snippets, the credentials passed are the same i think :)
I basically copy pasted the test files and changed the names a bit accordingly, its why i was surprised that it did not work...

Comment: But my bad, i should have looked at AND posted versions of JVM, etc. but i believe they are the same. In any case, i modified the encoded string and removed CRLFs and its working fine now so thanks a lot for the tip :)

Comment: Thanks. Workaround given in the link worked for me.. For those looking for quick solution in one line, remove newline character from the encoded bytes.. base64Encoded = base64Encoded.replaceAll("\n", "");

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your requestXML or any header value does not have any illegal characters and replace it like...

```
    aXmlRequest=aXmlRequest.replaceAll("\n", "");
```